# Internationalization (i18n) working, but accented characters aren't accented

Tags: spring, jsp, internationalization, locale, spring-mongo

I have a Spring MVC J2EE application that leverages Spring's `localeChangeInterceptor` and `CookieLocaleResolver` to render locale-driven support.  This is working, however when I try to encode letters with accent marks, the front-end fails to render them as expected.

Here's a snippet from my webmvc-config.xml file:

```
    <!-- Internalization and localization support -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Along with this I have some message_xx.properties files that contian my tags to render things out.  Included are tags like this with accent marks embedded: `district.manager.approval=Aprobaci&#243;n del Gerente de Distrito`.  My beef is that this displays exactly like this on the front-end instead of showing me `Aprobación del Gerente de Distrito`.

Any idea where I could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around a bit, it seems I left out a key detail: this only seems to be happening when I use JSTL `<c:set>` along with my Spring tags where the encoding does not work properly.  As it turns out, when using `<c:out>`, you need to accompany it with the `escapeXml="false"` attribute.  Here is what I did and it seems to be working appropriately now:

This is set in one page

```
<c:set var="headerScreenTitle">
    <spring:message code='district.manager.review.and.approval' />
</c:set>
```

This is consumed in an imported page

```
<c:out value="${headerScreenTitle}" escapeXml="false" />
```

And it handsomely gives me this:

`REVISIÓN Y APROBACIÓN DEL GERENTE DE DISTRITO`

Thanks everyone for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

The encoding of .properties files is usually (with few exceptions) expected to be Latin-1. Therefore for presenting Unicode content you need to escape the characters beyond Latin-1 repertoire:

`district.manager.approval=Aprobaci\u00F3n del Gerente de Distrito`

Or use XML properties files which can be encoded as UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

If you use html entities (e.g. &) and use `<spring:message code="property.name" />` tag to print values set "htmlEscape" attribute to "false":

```
<spring:message code="property.name" htmlEscape="false" />
```